# Matrix equations in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I need to solve a matrix equation such as $A=S^{-1}A~S$ for a given matrix A. Suppose that the matrices are $3*3$ and A is diagonal.

```
A = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1/2 + I Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, -1/2 - I Sqrt[3]/2}};
S[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, k_] := {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, k}};

Solve[A == Inverse[S] . A . S, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: You write `S[a_....]` then call it using just `S`.  So need to correct this. But  Mathematica finds only trivial solution ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgRgl.png)

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed the command as you said and It works.

Comment: `FindInstance[A . S == S . A,  S ∈ Matrices[Dimensions[A], Reals], 20]` for 20 random solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any diagonal matrix with non-zero entries will solve:

```
a = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1/2 + I  Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 
    0, -1/2 - I  Sqrt[3]/2}};
m = Array[s, {3, 3}];
ans = m /. Solve[m . a == a . m, Flatten[m]][[1]];
ans // MatrixForm
test = ans /. {s[1, 1] -> 1, s[2, 2] -> 2, s[3, 3] -> 3};
Inverse[test] . a . test === a
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I got the same answer.